# Как убрать блюр на фото

Tags: img

Как убрать блюр на фото? Срочно!

Comment: По вопросу непонятно, чего вы хотите. Вы хотите убрать CSS-свойство или Вам надо нечто другое? Уточните

Comment: Никак? За частую смысл блюра в том, что бы не могли понять что там было ранее.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде как-то делают обратную свертку.
https://habr.com/ru/post/147828/